# Images are not getting display on different browsers?

Tags: image, uiview, cross-browser

I am developing one website, in that i am showing some images on click event of some links.

and website is hosted on live web server.

But problem is that when i am visiting this site on my system, all images are getting displayed but when someone else is trying to access then images are not getting displayed.

In short, in some systems, website is working properly in chrome but in some systems images are not getting displayed.

According to me, may be it is an issue of browser compatibility, may be user browser is of lower version and that's why not showing images.

But i don't know whether i am thinking in a right way or not.

please suggest me how to solve such issue??

thanks in advance.

Comment: I would look at the code.

Comment: but if code is not working then how in some pc's site is working properly while in some systems its not getting display...??

Comment: For example, if you load images from javascript when you click on a link, it takes time to load images, in which case they would not display properly. Need to look at the code.

Comment: no @akonsu in this case, its not the scenario, not even a single image is getting displayed. initially  my associate was also not able to view images but once he updated his browser, all images became visible to him. Thats y i am confused why this is happening?

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue?